# Is const_cast on this pointer undefined behavior?

Tags: c++

In another question I ran across this code:

```
Real StatData::mean(Real trim) const
{
   // trim, pun not intended
   const_cast<StatData&>(*this).items.sort();
   // trim
}
```

cppreference also has an example on their [page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast):

```
struct type {
    type() :i(3) {}
    void m1(int v) const {
        // this->i = v;                 // compile error: this is a pointer to const
        const_cast<type*>(this)->i = v; // OK
    }
    int i;
};
```

Aside from the obvious question of why this would ever be practical, is it unsafe? Does it matter of the object created is const or not and more importantly, is the `this` pointer safe from undefined behavior because it's only marked `const` for that one function?

Comment: Depends what `items` is and what `sort` does...

Comment: `const StatData x; x.mean(Real());` >>> ???? >>> NOT PROFIT

Answer (score 9):

> Does it matter of the object created is const or not

Yes. If the object was created non-`const`, then no matter what you do the `const_cast` will be safe. Just a bad idea (because in general you don't *know* what the object was created non-`const`).

> the this pointer safe from undefined behavior because it's only marked const for that one function?

That's the wrong question really, but the point is that until you try to modify a `const` object you're safe. That means the `const_cast` itself is perfectly legal and well-defined, but if `items.sort()` modifies stuff (and we have to assume it does) then *that* operation results in UB.

Finally, although you've tried to gloss over this point in your question, the practicality of this is actually fundamental to the scenario: it's remarkably difficult to guarantee, even in this seemingly specific case, that the code is safe. So, *don't do it*. Despite your attempts at abstracting it away for the purposes of this question, I can't stress that enough.

Answer (score 6):

`const_cast` itself is *never* undefined behavior. It could be ill-formed, i.e fail to compile. But if it is well-formed (i.e. compilable) then it cannot produce undefined behavior by itself.

Undefined behavior might be triggered by what you do later with the [non-constant] access path you obtained with the help of `const_cast`. But it is a completely different story, not directly related to `const_cast`.

The code samples you posted so far are insufficient to tell whether they exhibit undefined behavior or not. It all depends on the external factors: on whether the object being modified is really declared as `const` or not. An attempt to modify `const` object triggers undefined behavior.

For example, for the `type` class above, this code triggers UB

```
const type t;
t.m1(42);  // <- undefined behavior
```

while this one does not

```
type t;
t.m1(42);
assert(t.i == 42);
```

Comment: Technically, I think `const_cast` itself may be undefined behaviour in one extremely rare corner case: in an expression where the order of evaluation is unspecified, the operand of `const_cast` may have been a valid pointer when that was evaluated, but become invalidated by the time the `const_cast` gets evaluated. (That's nit-picking, I know.)